# wordpress not saving updates to pages with admin-ajax.php error

Tags: wordpress, save, admin-ajax

I'm experiencing a strage behaviour of Wordpress trying to configure pages of my site.
After a random number of updates to a page when I click save button it remains in status saving and it's not possible to make any other changes without closing the page and login another time in Wordpress.
Inspecting with chrome tools I can see a post.php request pending and several admin-ajax.php request failed and canceled.

What can I do to solve this problem?